# Queue Name is not binding to azure service bus (Azure Logic Apps)

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am sending value to queue using Parameters file.
[image: parameter file]

In JSON file queue name is fetching like this.
[image: json]

After deployment in the Azure queue name is not binding.it should be test dev.
[image: logic app designer]

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this due to invalid template. Below is the template that worked for us.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "workflows_LogicApp12_name": {
      "defaultValue": "LogicApp12",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "connections_servicebus_1_externalid": {
      "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/<YourSubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<YourResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus-1",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "QueueName": {
      "defaultValue": "testdev",
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_LogicApp12_name')]",
            "location": "centralus",
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                  "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                      "defaultValue": {},
                      "type": "Object"
                    },
                    "QueueNamedev": {
                      "defaultValue": {},
                      "type": "String"
                    }
                  },
                    "triggers": {
                        "When_a_message_is_received_in_a_queue_(auto-complete)": {
                            "recurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Minute",
                                "interval": 3
                            },
                            "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Minute",
                                "interval": 3
                            },
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                          "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                              "connection": {
                                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus_1']['connectionId']"
                              }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameters('QueueNamedev')))}/messages/head",
                            "queries": {
                              "queueType": "Main"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {},
                    "outputs": {}
                },
              "parameters": {
                "$connections": {
                  "value": {
                    "servicebus_1": {
                      "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_1_externalid')]",
                      "connectionName": "servicebus-1",
                      "id": "/subscriptions/<YourSubscriptionID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/servicebus"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "QueueNamedev": {
                  "value": "[parameters('QueueName')]"
                }
              }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

You can also refer this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71857081/queue-name-is-not-binding-to-azure-logic-app-after-deployment) which I have answered