# Queue Name is not binding to azure logic app after deployment

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to deploy the Azure logic app to two environments *ie.* dev and prod.

I am using a single json file for the logic app and for the environments I have different parameter files. The Azure pipeline picks the parameter file as per the environment. All the parameters defined in the parameters files get bound during deployment, but I'm having issues with the queue name.

This is how I am defining parameters in the parameters files:

```json
"parameters": {
  "logicAppName": {
    "value": "Test-App-dev"
  },
  "QueueName": { "value": "testdev" }
}
```

This is how it is used in path variable in logic app json file:

[image]

But after deployment, the queue name is not reflecting on the Azure portal. This is how it looks like in the Azure portal:

[image]

Comment: Whenever possible, try to add a code block instead of a screenshot. I have swapped the first image with a code block as an example. I have also improved the phrasing to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end, we found that this is due to an invalid template. Here is how we could able to pull off the required value.

1. Created the below parameter

   ```
   "parameters": {
       ........
       ,
       "QueueName": {
         "defaultValue": "testdev",
         "type": "String"
       }
     }
   ```
2. Now you need to add the same in the template's parameter

   ```
   "parameters": {
               "$connections": {
                 "value": {
                   "servicebus_1": {
                     "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_1_externalid')]",
                     "connectionName": "servicebus-1",
                     "id": "***"
                   }
                 }
               },
               "QueueNamedev": {
                 "value": "[parameters('QueueName')]"
               }
             }
   ```
3. Declare the same in your definition's parameter

   ```
   "parameters": {
                   "$connections": {
                     "defaultValue": {},
                     "type": "Object"
                   },
                   "$QueueNamedev": {
                     "defaultValue": {},
                     "type": "String"
                   }
                 }
   ```

**RESULT:**
Finally, we could able to read its value as 'testdev'. You can check from parameters that the value of `QueueNamedev` is read as testdev.

[image]

Below is the template of my logic app

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "workflows_LogicApp12_name": {
      "defaultValue": "LogicApp12",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "connections_servicebus_1_externalid": {
      "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/<YourSubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<YourResourceGroup>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus-1",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "QueueName": {
      "defaultValue": "testdev",
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
            "apiVersion": "2017-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('workflows_LogicApp12_name')]",
            "location": "centralus",
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "definition": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                  "parameters": {
                    "$connections": {
                      "defaultValue": {},
                      "type": "Object"
                    },
                    "QueueNamedev": {
                      "defaultValue": {},
                      "type": "String"
                    }
                  },
                    "triggers": {
                        "When_a_message_is_received_in_a_queue_(auto-complete)": {
                            "recurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Minute",
                                "interval": 3
                            },
                            "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                                "frequency": "Minute",
                                "interval": 3
                            },
                            "type": "ApiConnection",
                          "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                              "connection": {
                                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus_1']['connectionId']"
                              }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameters('QueueNamedev')))}/messages/head",
                            "queries": {
                              "queueType": "Main"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                    },
                    "actions": {},
                    "outputs": {}
                },
              "parameters": {
                "$connections": {
                  "value": {
                    "servicebus_1": {
                      "connectionId": "[parameters('connections_servicebus_1_externalid')]",
                      "connectionName": "servicebus-1",
                      "id": "/subscriptions/<YourSubscriptionID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/servicebus"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "QueueNamedev": {
                  "value": "[parameters('QueueName')]"
                }
              }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```